# writing to a file with php is changing the original EOL type

Tags: php, newline

I am using `file_get_contents()` to retrieve an SVG file from an external URL, once I have it I am storing it as a variable then serving the file using a `header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');` the saved file retains the original EOL type, in this case it's `LF`.

However, I find that if I save the file with `file_put_contents()` then the EOL type in the saved file is changed to `CRLF`. I also just tested with `fwrite` but it has the same result, the saved file is changed to `CRLF`

Is there a way to use `file_put_contents` or `fwrite` and retain the EOL type or any other method that may better serve this purpose? I have checked the php docs on these functions but could not find a parameter that would help.. also searched this forum and google for a solution and could not find anything.. I have spent some time of this and feel its time to turn it over to others who may have better insight.

The files I am downloading may either contain `LF` OR `CRLF` so I am looking for a way to save the files and keep the original EOL type.

Here is a link to the original svg file: https://svgur.com/s/_ey

You can confirm the EOL type by opening the file with notepad++ and going to View -> Show Symbols -> Show End Of Line

Comment: How have you tested that it's actually `file_put_contents` that's changing the EOL?

Comment: yes, since serving the file with header() keeps the eol type i believe this confirm the file received by the stream is in its original form

Comment: i added a link to the svg file with `LF` eol type if you wanted to test.

Comment: If you try `file_put_contents('test.svg', file_get_contents('_ey.svg'));` you'll see that the EOLs are not changed. So it's surely not `file_put_contents` that's changing them. It must happen somewhere between loading and saving. But to help you with that you'd need to show that code.

Comment: looks like i did have an error in my code. the file i was saving with file_put_contents had the wrong file name and therefore saving the wrong file.. cant believe i looked over that. thanks for the second pair of eyes.